# LocalEulerAngle is different from inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

What i know about unity rotation is that, it show euler angle on inspector while behind the scene it use Quaternion. But I am surprised that my local euler angle and inspector rotation y are not same when my inspector value change from a positive number to a negative number. Why

I am using this

```
transform.localEulerAngles.y
```

to get local euler angles. 
I noticed that it increasing in positive 
like:

*Inspector **:** Code LocalEulerAngle*

97.04301: 97.04301  //matched

158.659: 158.659   //matched

-179.094 : 180.9064  //not matched

-170.812 : 189.1875 //not matched

Comment: They do match, it simply never considers negative values. -179.094 isn't an actual angle, but 180.906 is. It's basically 360 - 179.094 which equals the 180.906 you see in the LocalEulerAngle. So technically the 180.906 is the angle you are looking for, it just won't give a negative angle.

Comment: so why not my insepctor showing that value? what inspector actually represent

Answer (score 0):

Unity, and every popular game engine for that matter, uses [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) for all sorts of rotational representation and computation. Using Euler angles, you often run into issues like [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) and hence they are never used internally.

What you see in the inspector is for your own understanding and visualization. Quaternions are difficult (I so mean it!) to grasp so they are always hidden from the not-so-mathematical-genius common user. The values retrieved in code are quaternions represented as Euler, whereas the inspector values are, well, inspector values.

Comment: what is this farhan " whereas the inspector values are, well, inspector values"

Comment: By that, I meant that you are free to put rotation of e.g. -900 in X in the inspector. That value, though it means 2.5 full 360 rotations to you, internally it will be something totally different in quaternion representation.
Refer to this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/645903/please-explain-quaternions.html

Answer (score 0):

`localEulerAngles` use values between 0 and 360, as briefly stated in the [documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) They are mostly informative.

Comment: So what is the inspector value?

Comment: The inspector value is angle converted from the Quaternion, same as `localEulerAngles`. But unlike `localEulerAngles`, inspector values are not clamped between 0 and 360. To convert the value from inspector, just add/ subtract 360 until the value is between 0 and 360.